# React-router and Express server on same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am developing a website that uses react and react-router for the frontend and express for the server. I'm trying to implement session based authentication by using express-session, however, the only way that I've been able to get the cookie to save in the browser was by having the express server run on the same port that react-router is (localhost:3000).

I'm not sure how to phrase this question, but is this "OK"? There doesn't appear to be any obvious problems caused by doing this but I'm not sure if having them both run on the same port is "good" or "bad".

Could there be any problems caused by having react-router and express running on the same port? If so, how can I get express to save the cookie on a port that's different from the express server itself?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. YES this is bad, the solution is to set up a proxy for create react app

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/